# How to display HBase data-lineage in Apache Atlas?

Tags: hbase, apache-atlas, data-lineage, data-governance

I am testing Apache Atlas data governance tool to display data lineage of a NoSQL database.

I understand that HBase is the only supported NoSQL database as of now (input metadata source).

I've set up Apache Atlas 2.0 in an environment having functional Apache HBase and Apache Solr instances. (from https://atlas.apache.org/InstallationSteps.html)

I created few testing tables with `hbase shell` and was able to import it into Atlas with `import-hbase.sh` script.
I also configured HBase Hook to keep feeding my data to Atlas on the fly.

Since everything was working fine (data being successfully transferred to Atlas), I was expecting to see some data lineage after few manipulation on my testing data. But Apache Atlas keeps showing a "No lineage data found" message in the UI.

I did some research and found out that the only lineage examples on the Internet were made with Hive.

So my question is, does Apache Atlas support displaying HBase data lineage? If so, has anybody succeeded doing it? Is there any configuration to set up?

Thanks for your help